# C#.NET MVC4 - Windows Authentication and custom user data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, membership

The client I work for at the moment wants to use their Active Directory logins with single sign-on when connecting from a domain computer. I have however no experience with Windows Authentication.

The problem however is, that I need to reference the users in the database. Also, the users already should be in the database even if they haven't logged on yet. (Guessing I'm syncing with active directory with LDAP every night??) The reason for that is that other users should be able to assign the user to specific tasks.

See the following basic diagram:
[image]

My question is:
Should I use a MemberShipProvider or just extend IPrincipal?
Am I thinking the right way by syncing every night?
How can I prevent the user data is fetched from the database every request?

Answer (score 0):

Use membership provider to connect to LDAP for you, then authenticate with the ValidateUser method in the provider.

Comment: That way I have single sign-on on the domain computers will I?

Comment: Yes you will then have single sign on